# Get users with a list of associated seasons

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’m trying to get a list of users with a list of their associated seasons in Postgres. They’re connected to a pivot table.

I am completely lost on how to do the query. I know just joining all 3 tables in a query will return all the rows I need, so technically I could just do an array.reduce with JavaScript, but I think a proper query might be more efficient.

Any ideas?

tables:

### users

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jake |
| 2 | Adam |

### seasons

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Fall |
| 2 | Spring |

### user_season

| user_id | season_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

## Desired Output

to send to frontend:

| user_id | user_name | seasons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jake | [{ name: “Fall”, id: 1}, {name: “Spring”, id: 2}] |
| 2 | Adam | [{name: “Spring”, id: 2}] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
SELECT u.id AS user_id, u.name AS user_name,
       '[' || STRING_AGG('{ "name": "' || s.name || '", "id":' || s.id || 
       '}', ', ') || ']' AS seasons
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_season us ON us.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN seasons s ON s.id = us.season_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
ORDER BY u.id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Unreal how quick you got this. But this works as I need. I can just JSON.parse the string on the frontend. Thank you!